# Процедура в access

Tags: access, sql

Добрый день. Не могу разобраться с процедурой в акцесе. В графе Тип запроса выбираю обновление и появляются стандартные update...set. Предположим что есть таблица, в которой интересуют след.колонки: Название(оно может повторяться, по нему стоит группировка) и номер. Так вот нумерацию нужно сделать от 1 до N, в рамках названия. Например:

Название №

Название1 1

Название1 2

Название1 3

Название2 1

Название1 2

Не могу придумать как прописать условие для цикла (пока предыдущий элемент равен следующему) и не знаю почему ругается на обновление переменных, в ms sql server они объявляются в начале...Прошу вашей помощи :)

```
declare @n int
set @n=1

WHILE Таблица.Название???

BEGIN

UPDATE Таблица

@n=@n+1

SET Таблица.Номер=@n

END
```

Answer (score 1):

в запросах акцесса нет переменных, только параметры (не считая запросов к серверу). зато можно обновлять несколько таблиц:

update a
set b.number = iif(a.name = b.name; b.number + 1; 1), b.name = a.name, a.number = b.number
from Таблица a, Таблица_с_одной_записью b;

Answer (score 0):

Если вы хотите написать процедуру VBA, то создайте recordset и обходите его в цикле.

А вообще мне не понятно, зачем вам нужна нумерация в таблице, которая постоянно будет съезжать при каждом добавлении данных. Нумеруйте записи там, где это нужно, например при выводе в отчете.